# Set standby timeout for Seagate drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, power-management, ata

I recently built a NAS running Debian 12 with 3 3To Seagate Iron Wolf.
To save power, I would like the drives to enter standby mode after a 30 minutes.

For this, I used `hdparm -S 241 <drive>` to set the timeout, and `hdparm -B 127 <drive>` to allow drive to spin down (cf. [hdparm man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hdparm.8.html)).
But now drives goes to standby mode after only 1 minute.

Adjusting the value to 240 (20min) and 120 (10min) do not help.

`hdparm -S` issues ATA Idle command which is code 0xE3, from the [manual of the drives](https://www.seagate.com/content/dam/seagate/migrated-assets/www-content/product-content/ironwolf/en-us/docs/100807039r.pdf), page 17 :

> Standby mode
> The drive enters Standby mode when the host sends a Standby Immediate command. If the host has set the standby timer, the
> drive can also enter Standby mode automatically after the drive has been inactive for a specifiable length of time. The standby
> timer delay is established using a **Standby** or **Idle** command. In Standby mode, the drive buffer is enabled, the heads are parked
> and the spindle is at rest. The drive accepts all commands and returns to Active mode any time disk access is necessary

So, from my understanding I could also send ATA Standby command (code 0xE2) to set the standby timeout ? Or do I need to set both ?
`hdparm` does not support 0xE2 command, is there a tool which does ?

Finally, the manual also says that the drives does not support APM feature, but I can run `hdparm -B 128` to prevent drives spining down, why ?